# ClickableSpan isn't highlighted when I click some word, updateDrawState is called many times

Tags: android

1. When I select some word it doesn't get red (background for span)
2. I'm also interesting why `updateDrawState` is being called so many times when I click only once and during inflating (creating span for the first time).

.

```
CharSequence text = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten";
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);

int start = 0;
int end;
int n = text.length() - 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (text.charAt(i) == ' ' || i == n) {
        end = i;

        if (i == n) {
            end = i + 1;
        }

        final CharSequence word = text.subSequence(start, end);
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                Log.i(TAG, "#1 onClick " + word);
            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                Log.i(TAG, "#2 updateDrawState");
            }
        };

        Log.i(TAG, "#3 setSpan " + word);
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        start = i + 1;
    }
}
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.RED);
textView.setMovementMethod(new LinkMovementMethod());
textView.setText(ss);
```

**Logs:** (onCreate, only one click on word "Four")

```
11-26 17:13:40.236 I/LOG: #3 setSpan one
11-26 17:13:40.236 I/LOG: #3 setSpan two
11-26 17:13:40.236 I/LOG: #3 setSpan three
11-26 17:13:40.236 I/LOG: #3 setSpan four
11-26 17:13:40.236 I/LOG: #3 setSpan five
11-26 17:13:40.236 I/LOG: #3 setSpan six
11-26 17:13:40.236 I/LOG: #3 setSpan seven
11-26 17:13:40.237 I/LOG: #3 setSpan eight
11-26 17:13:40.237 I/LOG: #3 setSpan nine
11-26 17:13:40.237 I/LOG: #3 setSpan ten
11-26 17:13:40.273 I/LOG: #2 updateDrawState
11-26 17:13:40.274 I/LOG: #2 updateDrawState
11-26 17:13:40.274 I/LOG: #2 updateDrawState
11-26 17:13:40.274 I/LOG: #2 updateDrawState
11-26 17:13:40.348 I/LOG: #2 updateDrawState
... a lot of updateDrawState (> 300)
11-26 17:14:00.977 I/LOG: #2 updateDrawState
11-26 17:14:00.977 I/LOG: #2 updateDrawState
11-26 17:14:00.977 I/LOG: #2 updateDrawState
11-26 17:14:00.977 I/LOG: #2 updateDrawState
11-26 17:14:00.978 I/LOG: #1 onClick four
```

so 1 onCreate and one onClick and we get 349 calls to `updateDrawState` method (insane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the first problem #1 - bug with `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.android.edittext.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I just changed it to `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.android.edittext.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Highlighting works now:

[image]

Problem #2 - I'm still interesting why it calls `updateDrawState` so many times (I understand it calls this method for every word, but then it becomes again from the first word like 3 cycles in onCreate/View (init) and 5-10 cycles when you click on the word, so for each word it called many times)

Comment: @RamachandranA not really, actually it doesn't matter really, seems it doesn't effect performance anyway, also it depends on how many spans do you have